# How to find sum of values with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My xml file looks like this

```
<xxx>
    <fff>1</fff>
</xxx>
<xxx>
    <fff>1</fff>
</xxx>
```

And I want to find the sum of values in nodes . I was trying like this:

```
var sum = from c in el.Elements()
         select new {I don't know what to write here}
```

and then iterating through sum, but I want to do it in one query.

How the query will be look like?

Comment: `And I want to find sum of values from`. I guess sum of fields `fff` but what if there are more integer fields in your real xml? Why don't you post your **real** problem?

Comment: yes.there are another integer fields. But I thought it is possible to get value only from this field

Comment: I want in query form. I can do myself like this. The troubles are with query form.

Comment: So you want us to parse a hypothetical xml and give a correct answer.

Comment: I want a query which parse xml file and summarize values from field <fff> but in query form(like in my question)

Comment: And a new requirement: `I want in query form`

Comment: Why don't you try to read some docs for such simple cases? I am sure you can find millions of documents

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this?

```
int sum = root.Descendants("fff").Sum(e => (int) e);
```

Comment: What if there were an xml part `<yyy><fff>exception</fff></yyy>` ?

Comment: @L.B Hey, don't ask me. I just provided a simple one-query solution that was asked.

Answer (score 3):

I think it will be more like this:

```
int sum = root.Descendants("fff").Sum(e => int.Parse(e.Value));
```

Comment: What is the difference from other answer?

Comment: e will actually be an XElement which has a property called Value which is a string containing the text of the fff element. I don't think Balazs answer will actually compile.

Comment: It will, thanks to Linq to XML magic and does the same thing - just much more concise than your answer

Comment: @BrokenGlass fair point, I hadn't realised that XElement has an explicit cast operator to an int!

Comment: It is more concise but less explicit, personally I'd prefer more readable and explicit code than short code :)

Comment: int.Parse will throw an exception on <fff>exception</fff>.  Use TryParse, or Convert.ToInt32.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 will also throw a FormatException. If you've validated your xml against a strict XSD prior to the linq query then you won't have a problem. Also, the explicit cast that Balazs used will throw an exception if the xelement does not contain a value which can be parsed to an int http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348319.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the exception case you need to use TryParse not Parse, e.g.

```
int sum = el.Descendants("fff").Sum (e => 
    { 
        int v;
        return int.TryParse(e.Value, out v) ? v : 0;
    });
```